# how to resolve target .NET Framework with Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i am new to development with Xamarian platform.Now i just want to run application to targetFramework 4.5. but there diff targetframework listed as below. how i resolve that please help me out.[image]

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  4.5 is almost 10 years old

Comment: Is the situation that you need to link with a dll built on Framework 4.5 (that you don't have the source to)? OR is it that you have a lot of source code that originally targetted 4.5 - but you do have the ability to rebuild a new dll or exe?

Answer (score 0):

- See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard - in the table, note that .Net Framework 4.5 supports the newer net-standard up to 1.1. So choose `.NET Standard 1.1`. Or if you can require .Net Framework 4.5.1 and newer, choose `.NET Standard 1.2`.
- Or better, whatever dependency is forcing you to use `Framework 4.5`, talk to the vendor, get them to rebuild for `.NET Core 3.1` or the new `.NET 6`.
- If you really must support .Net "Framework" APIs, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/connect/net-introducing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core, for a (no longer being updated) solution that allows your newer code to be "Net Core", yet work with legacy .net APIs.

Be aware all this is "legacy" - Microsoft's goal is to move everyone to `.NET 6`.